# listing file is specific order linux

Tags: linux, bash, file-listing

I would like to ask you for help with some script.
I have files in one directory with one extension:

```
1_of_meany_files.ext
2_of_meany_files.ext
3_of_meany_key1_files.ext
5_of_meany_files.ext
6_key2_of_meany_files.ext
```

Now i'm trying build file.txt with list of these files but in specific order:

```
3_of_meany_key1_files.ext
6_key2_of_meany_files.ext
1_of_meany_files.ext
2_of_meany_files.ext
5_of_meany_files.ext
```

I would be appreciate for help.
Thanks 
Marcin

==EDIT==

Hi, Thanks for your help. 
The scripts are working fine. However I have problem with one thing:
If the key word has a digit inside it works perfect. 
But the key words can be without digits (S114 or S_114)
then these scripts aren't works. What can I do with this?
General I would like to sort files and put one on the top of the list with the key (S114 or S_114).
So the files after sorting can looks like this:

Option One

```
    one_file_S114_text.ext
    rest_of_files_1.ext
    rest_of_files_2.ext
    rest_of_files_3.ext
```

Option Two

```
    one_file_S_114_text.ext
    rest_of_files_1.ext
    rest_of_files_2.ext
    rest_of_files_3.ext
```

In directory can be only one file with the key, but the key can be S114 or S_114

Thanks for your time
regard Marcin

Comment: I don't understand the desired ordering. By what criterion do you want to sort them?

Comment: I wont to have on the top of list file with the key1, second file with  key2. For rest of files I don't need special order (can be direct from ls command.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, because you want the files with no key in the end, so you can't just do `print $2+0,$0` in the awk command. However, this awk-sort-cut pipeline should do what you want:

```
$ printf "%s\n" * | awk -F'_key' '{print $2+0==0?1000000:$2+0,$0}'| sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2-
3_of_meany_key1_files.ext
6_key2_of_meany_files.ext
1_of_meany_files.ext
2_of_meany_files.ext
5_of_meany_files.ext
```

Answer (score 2):

With perl:

```
perl -e 'print"$_\n"for sort{($a=~/key(\d+)/?$1:1e+9)-($b=~/key(\d+)/?$1:1e+9)}<*>'
```